How to setup Google Analytics 4 with Quasar SPA Vuejs app
Having a hard time finding documentation or resources on setup of GA4 tracking for Vuejs 3 Quasar based app using typescript.
Would be nice to figure out how to setup vue-gtag package with it.
If anyone has expirience - please help.
Looks like I would add it via quasar new boot command and setup the relative analytics boot file but not all sure how it would work.

Gave a try to this one? https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/issues/383#issuecomment-1266505846 It's nothing too specific tho, as shown here: https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag#add-plugin-to-your-application A Quasar app is still a regular VueJS app so far.

Hi! could you solve this?
